# Replacement of a JPanel element without adding to the end of the panel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I posted a question earlier about this but the solution never worked and now it's under different circumstances. I'm making a "penny pitch" program, that, when the "confirm" button is pressed, a randomized number will dictate which spot on the board(the board is fill with image icons) the "penny" will fall, and in the process it removes the image icon that use to occupant the chosen space.

I set up a GridBagLayout to constrain each icon down, and my button has no problem removing the chosen spot, but it can not find a way for it to add a new icon in it's place. It just gets adds onto the end of the JPanel.

Heres my coding for the button:

```
private class AddListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
    if (a.getSource()== confirm) {
        if (numberToss >0){
                thrown = pitch.nextInt(25) + 1;
                System.out.println(thrown);
           //kol is an array to check for repeated numbers in randomization
        if (kol.contains(thrown)==false){               
            input.remove(spot.get(thrown));
            //spot is a map to set icons down with a association with number
            spot.put(thrown, bSet);
            input.add((spot.put(thrown, bSet)));
            repaint();
            kol.add(thrown);
            }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your toss landed onto an occupied spot; you receive no points");
            }
        numberToss--;   
        }
        else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Out of tosses.");  
        }

      }

    }
```

Anyone happen to know how to replace the new icon (bSet) with the former? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a cheat you might be able to use, [`GridBagLayout#getConstraints(Component)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getConstraints-java.awt.Component-), which returns the constraints for the given object, so you could, for example, get the current constraints for the component you want to remove and use those when you add the new component...as an idea. You could also use a `JButton` or `JLabel` and simply swap the icon ...

Comment: I have actually tried that, but it said it couldn't find the symbol ".getConstraints(comp)". I've already imports javax.swing.*, java.awt.*, and java.util.*, so I couldn't find a reason for it to reject it.

Comment: Did you use the instance of `GridBagLayout` you're using for the panel

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The coding I posted is already a minimal example; I took out section not necessary for understanding the program. I'll edit and post a simplified version the the whole coding as well then.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have the bit of coding `private JPanel input = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout ())` and I use `input.getConstraints(comp)` when I try to use it.

Comment: `getConstraints` isn't a method of `JPanel`, as my comments (and the JavaDocs state), it's a method of `GridBagLayout`